# Books on Rings without Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, rngs

I was just wondering if anybody knows of any good books or articles that study rings (and algebras) without (or not necessarily with) identity. I have gone through Thomas Hungerford's *Algebra* textbook (and loved it), but every book I have read afterwards on noncommutative algebra (Farb and Dennis' *Noncommutative Algebra* and T. Y. Lam's *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*) have assumed that all rings are unitary. Could anyone give me a good reference please? Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jacobson's *Structure of rings* develops a bit of ring theory without assuming identity. Also Gardner and Wiegandt's book *Radical Theory of Rings* does not assume identities.

Any book on $C^*$ algebras would also have to deal with rings missing identity.

Answer (score 4):

1. Hungerford's *Algebra*
2. Bresar's *Introduction to Noncommutative Algebra*.
3. Behrens's *Ring Theory*.
4. Warner's *Modern Algebra* (Section 32).
5. Grove's *Algebra* (Chapter V).
6. Herstein's *Noncommutative Rings*.
7. McCoy's *The Theory of Rings*.
8. Jacobson's *Structure of Rings*.
9. Gardner and Wiegandt's *Radical Theory of Rings*.